# Can you set an html docType on a Visualforce Email Template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, doctype

I can't find any way to control docType of any type of email in Salesforce. First I tried Custom and then I tried Visualforce. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: quick question -- why would you even need that?

Comment: @kurunve it's a fairly common best practice for html emails: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/correct-doctype-to-use-in-html-email/, https://github.com/mailgun/transactional-email-templates/blob/master/templates/inlined/action.html, https://github.com/zurb/foundation-emails-template/blob/master/src/layouts/default.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is the hack I found to do that

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="<!DOCTYPE html>" />
```

with `escape=false` the value will be rendered as is